# Mock and verify 2 methods public static void and public static boolean from same class using PowerMockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have a class say `ClassA` which has to 3-4 `public static` methods out of which my requirement is to mock 2 methods one is `public static void` and other is `public static boolean`.

Code snippet below

```
class ClassA{
   public static boolean isConnected(){
     //....
   }
   public static void doSomething(){
    //....
   }
  public static void doSomethingMore(){
    //....
   }
}
```

Now I have another class say `ClassB` has `method1()` calling `ClassA.isConnected()` and `ClassA.doSomething()` as below

```
class ClassB{
   public void method1(){
      if(ClassA.isConnected()){
        //...
      }else{
        ClassA.doSomething()
      }
   }
}
```

Now I want to do unit testing for `method1()`, so I'm trying to mock `isConnected()` and `doSomething()` using `PowerMockito`, as below

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassA.class})
public class ClassBTest{ 

@Test
public void testMethod1{
     //variables
     ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    //mock static non-void method
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassA.class);
    PowerMockito.when(ClassA.isConnected()).thenReturn(false);
    //mock static void method
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ClassA.class);
    ClassA.doSomething();
    //execute
    classB.method1();

    //verify static non-void method called
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(1)); 
    ClassA.isConnected();
    //Verify static void method called
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(1)); 
    **ClassA.doSomething();**//getting error at this line
 }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Wanted but not invoked com.example.utils.common.ClassA.doSomething(
    );

However, there were other interactions with this mockcom.example.utils.common.ClassA.isConnected();

com.example.utils.common.ClassA.doSomethingMore(
    );

.
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:124)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:63)
    at com.example.utils.common.ClassA.doSomething(ClassA.java)
    at com.example.utils.common.ClassBTest.testMethod1(ClassBTest.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: perhaps your methods should not be static ........ saves you a hell of a lot of issues

Comment: Not sure about it, but why that `PowerMockito.spy(ClassA.class);` line? First you mock it and then you tell it that you just want to spy? I tend not to use PowerMockito - refactoring is most often the better choice - but that somehow sounds strange.

Comment: @Blundell : this is existing project ...adding unit testing this.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz that line is typo mistake. its not there in test case i have removed it from question later on. please try this scenario. if you get the answer

Comment: The code works fine for me, after I switch out `times(2)` with `times(1)` for the `isConnected()` verfication (mock preparation doesn't count). Then it succeeds without any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to getting mocking of statics correct. You can amend legacy code to improve testability.

The below example keeps the static methods incase they are used elsewhere in the codebase. Obviously once all static method calls have been removed you can remove them from here (and then get rid of `instance` as well).

```
class ClassA{
   private static ClassA instance = new ClassA();

   public static boolean isConnected(){
     return instance.isConnected();
   }

   public boolean isConnected(){
     //....
   }

   public static void doSomething(){
    instance.doSomething();
   }

   public void doSomething(){
    //....
   }       

   public static void doSomethingMore(){
    instance.doSomethingMore();
   }

   public void doSomethingMore(){
    //....
   }
}
```

`ClassB` has a setter, you could change this to a constructor dependency or injection framework depending on your code. The setter is package protected so that it has minimal visibility. The [annotation VisibleForTesting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/VisibleForTesting.html) is optional and just highlights the reason for the setter.

```
class ClassB{

   private ClassA classA = new ClassA();

   @VisibleForTesting
   void setClassA(ClassA classA) {
        this.classA = classA;
   }

   public void method1(){
      if(classA.isConnected()){
        //...
      }else{
        classA.doSomething()
      }
   }
}
```

The test is simplified without the need for PowerMock:

```
public class ClassBTest{ 

@Test
public void testMethod1{
     //variables
     ClassB classB = new ClassB();
     ClassA mockClassA = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);
     classB.setClassA(mockClassA);
     // mock expected behaviour
     Mockito.when(mockClassA.isConnected()).thenReturn(false);

    //execute
    classB.method1();

    Mockito.verify(mockClassA, times(2)).isConnected();
    Mockito.verify(mockClassA).doSomething();
 }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer constructor injection for this kind of testing, but it has the same effect.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz same, I wrote that in the desc, but I don't know the state of his legacy code so was trying for minimal disruption

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to write testcase without changing legacy source code. PowerMockito supports Mocking Static method  https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13

Comment: @PallaviG How come you don't want to / can't clean the code up?

Comment: @PallaviG., that's what PowerMock is for - if you really can't refactor the code in question (which can also happen, for example, if you are bound to some framework of questionalable code quality). As I wrote above, the code works for me, perhaps you've got some version problem here.

Comment: i am using the these version libraries dependencies in build.gradle , with java 1.8                                                                                          dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // Unit testing dependencies
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Mockito
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    compile ('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4') 
    compile ('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4')                     }    So, think library version is not a problem